# Error :- Activity Main can't be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, jsp

I searched this error and tried all available solutions but still getting this error. I am new to android so please help to rectify and remove this error.
I am fully aware that this error is somewhat associated with .R file of android.

I am using eclipse and getting 2 error
1- "activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field"
2- List is a raw type. Reference to generic type.

Following is MainActivity code. This code is written to calculate nearest located Latlong distance..

```
package com.example.latlong;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.FileWriter;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.List;
  import android.R;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.location.Location;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Environment;

  import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
  import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Double latToCompare=0.0, longToCompare=0.0;
    float shortestDistance = 0.0f;
    Boolean isDistanceComparedFirstTime = true;
    Boolean isFirstRowInCSV1 = true, isFirstRowInCSV2 = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  /////// Error1 Line


        createDirIfNotExists("/windows/Pictures/LatLongFiles");

        String csvFilename1 =     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/windows/Pictures/LatLongFiles/Data.csv";
        String csvFilename2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/windows/Pictures/LatLongFiles/SourceFile.csv";
        String csvFilename3 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/windows/Pictures/LatLongFiles/OutputFile.csv";

        CSVReader csvReader1 = null;
        CSVReader csvReader2 = null;
        CSVWriter csvWriter3 = null;    

        List csvFile2List = null;     /////////////   Error2  Line
```

I know this error is not new to you android guys but i tried everything and still stuck on this error.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try cleaning the project. There might be some errors in your any of the XML files which is preventing the `R.java` file to be created successfully.

Comment: @PrerakSola You are right

Answer (score 2):

Removed `import android.R;` And clean and rebuild your project

```
import your_application_package_name.R;
```

Comment: How i can remove this import R file as i m using it at setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: @AkshayKumar You will use your packagename.R

Comment: @AkshayKumar Did you try my logic .Use this way . i hope it will helps you

Comment: Still getting same error..  I used  import com.example.latlong.R;

Comment: @AkshayKumar Now clean and rebuild and restart your project

Comment: @AkshayKumar Using eclipse or android studio ?

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya .. I am using Eclipse and the problem is that this is not generating R.java file..

Comment: @AkshayKumar which version and sdk  version ?? switch to android stdio

Comment: @AkshayKumar Update you Android SDK Tools

Comment: Okay, may be that's the reason why i m getting this error.. I will let you know once i am done with it..

Comment: @AkshayKumar Whats the result ?

Comment: @Amiya I un installed Eclipse and tried to run this project on Android studio.. But getting Error of gradle sync failed.. Due to improper JDK Path in SDK... Right now tried to remove this error..

Answer (score 0):

Error 1 indicates that the build system cannot find a layout file called "activity_main.xml". Verify that you have such a layout file.

Error 2 is simply a warning that informs you that you are using a raw type rather than a generic type. Add a type parameter that indicates the type of objects that are to reside in your list, e.g.:

```
List<YourTypeHere> csvFile2List = null;
```

Comment: I already have activity_main.xml file in layout folder.. And it is not showing any error..

Answer (score 0):

Delete `import.android.R;` and in place of it, add `import com.example.latlong.R;` if **com.example.latlong** is your package name.

Or if this is not your package name, see your manifest file for the package name. And add `import YourPackageName.R;` instead of `import.android.R;` where **YourPackageName** is the name of your package.